# using grep in if statment in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I am a newbie in UNIX I am trying to write a script that will grep on a certain word and print the line and file where it was found if its available and echo not available if it wasn't found

here is my code

```
#!/bin/csh
foreach file(`cat file1`)
set a=`echo $file | grep -n "ok"  `
if(" $a" -ne 0 ) then
echo "$a" | echo $file
else
echo "not found"
endif
end
```

Comment: Unless you have very specific reasons to prefer `csh`, a common recommendation is to stick to a Bourne-compatible shell for both scripts and interactive use. Both Bash and Zsh are popular and widely available.

Comment: Is `file1` a list of files in which you want to search for the string `ok`?

Comment: Although this doesn't do exactly what you want, it's not entirely clear to me what it is that you want, so perhaps you're content with `grep -f file1 *`.  (This will generate error messages for directories, and will not emit warnings for strings in `file1` that are not found.)

Answer (score 0):

the correct syntax is

```
#!/bin/csh
foreach file(`cat file1`)
set a=`echo $file | grep -n "ok"  `
if(" $a" != " " ) then
echo "$a"
echo $file
else
echo "not found"
endif
end
```